# How to change display text in item template based on eval in gridview?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a GridView and there is a column named status. On displaying the value in this column i have used itemtemplate. Currently, it shows the result of value of EVAL but i want to show text based on the values of eval.

```
 <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server"/>
 <Columns>
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Status">
       <ItemTemplate>
        <%# Eval("ICB_SUBS_STATUS")%>
       </ItemTemplate>
       <EditItemTemplate>
           <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1"  runat="server" SelectedValue='<%# Eval("ICB_SUBS_STATUS")%>'>
           <asp:ListItem Value = '0'>Applet not installed.</asp:ListItem>
           <asp:ListItem Value = '1'>ICB Service not activated. Applet installed.</asp:ListItem>
           <asp:ListItem Value = '2'>Active ICB Subscriber. Applet installed.</asp:ListItem>
           <asp:ListItem Value = '3'>Subscriber deactivated ICB. Applet installed.</asp:ListItem>
           </asp:DropDownList>
       </EditItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
 </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

As in above case, on edit template the dropdownlist text is shown based on value. Also, i want to show text on normal display of gridview. Any idea and suggestion will be very helpful!! Sorry, if my english is poor!

Comment: By 'normal display of gridview', do you mean a read-only label for the same field that is the dropdown here?

Comment: @Floyd Pink: yes. I mean on edit, the text is displayed instead of 0 or 1 or 2 or 3. I want to display text not on edit also. sry if my english is poor.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create a method in your code behind that translates this value to a human readable string.

```
protected string Translate_ICB_SUBS_STATUS(int ICB_SUBS_STATUS)
{
    switch (ICB_SUBS_STATUS)
    {
        case 0:
             return "Applet not installed.";
        case 1:
             return "ICB Service not activated. Applet installed.";
        ...

    }
}
```

Then in your binding, use the method

```
<ItemTemplate>
<%# this.Translate_ICB_SUBS_STATUS(Int32.Parse(Container.DataItem("ICB_SUBS_STATUS").ToString())) %>
</ItemTemplate>
```

Comment: You may want to use an array of values and display members to prevent duplication of code here but this is the quick and dirty solution.

Comment: Non-invocable member 'System.Web.UI.IDataItemContainer.DataItem' cannot be used like a method.