# set the text of GridView rows corresponding to the values of DataTable fields

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, datatable

I've a GridView its DataSource is from a data base table. I want to display different texts in the rows as per the database values. 
Here, for the column *Billed For*, if the field `BILLING_DTLS_STATUS` has value 1 it should display "NORTH COUNTER", has value 2 it should display "SOUTH COUNTER" and has value 3 it should display "MAIN COUNTER".

Also I've a button `btnBilled`, if the field `BILL_STATUS` has value 1 the button text should be "DISABLE" and if 0 the text should have "ENABLE".

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1"
    runat="server"
    AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
    OnRowDataBound="GridView1_RowDataBound">            
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="S No." ItemStyle-Width="15%" >
            <ItemTemplate>
                <%#Container.DataItemIndex+1 %>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:BoundField
            DataField="BILLING_DTLS_STATUS"
            HeaderText="Billed For">
            <ItemStyle VerticalAlign="Top" />
        </asp:BoundField>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="BILLING_SUB_TYPE"
            HeaderText="Billing Type">
            <ItemStyle VerticalAlign="Top" />
        </asp:BoundField>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="BILLIG_AMT"
            HeaderText="Billing Amount">
            <ItemStyle VerticalAlign="Top" />
        </asp:BoundField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="STATUS">
        <ItemTemplate >
            <asp:Button ID="btnBilled" Text="" runat="server" />
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

I've initally changed the value of `BILLING_DTLS_STATUS` and then filled the GridView, but I think this approach is not correct. Also how can I set the text of button as per the value of `BILL_STATUS` field.

```
public void Get_Billing_Type()
        {
            try
            {
                DataTable dt = new DAL_Set_Billing_Type().Get_Billing_Type();
                foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
                {
                    switch(row[0].ToString())
                    {
                        case "1":
                            {
                                row["BILLING_DTLS_STATUS"] = "NORTH COUNTER";
                                break;
                            }
                        case "2":
                            {
                                row["BILLING_DTLS_STATUS"] = "SOUTH COUNTER";
                                break;
                            }
                        case "3":
                            {
                                row["BILLING_DTLS_STATUS"] = "MAIN COUNTER";
                                break;
                            }
                    }
                }
                GridView1.DataSource = dt;
                GridView1.DataBind();
            }
            catch (Exception) {            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not create a Method that returns the correct type based on the `BILLING_DTLS_STATUS`

```
public string Get_Billing_Type(int type)
{
    if (type == 1)
    {
        return "NORTH COUNTER";
    }
    else if (type == 2)
    {
        return "SOUTH COUNTER";
    }
    else if (type == 3)
    {
        return "MAIN COUNTER";
    }
    else
    {
        return "NO COUNTER";
    }
}
```

Then in the GridView you can get the correct value.

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Billing Status">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <%# Get_Billing_Type(Convert.ToInt32(Eval("BILLING_DTLS_STATUS"))) %>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

For a button that has only 2 options, you could use a ternary operator. You could also use the same technique as mentioned above and create a method for it.

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Billing Status">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text='<%# Convert.ToBoolean(Eval("BILL_STATUS")) ? "DISABLE" : "ENABLE" %>' />
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Answer (score 0):

[Similar to this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14723162/how-to-change-display-text-in-item-template-based-on-eval-in-gridview)

My two cents:-

- if only two values are there, you can use ternary operator.
- Also, I prefer to change display text to client from Database query 
  itself(SP, Linq)